# update Ubuntu 16.04.1 to 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates

Hy!

How can i update my 16.04.1 to 16.04.3 ?

I tried:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

But

```
uname -a
```

said :

```
Linux lawyer 4.10.0-35-generic #39~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 09:02:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/961143/edit) and add the results of `lsb_release -d`.

Comment: @gorbedani Please don't edit your question to add a solution, if you found one. You can post an answer instead and also accept that one later to mark the question as solved. Thanks for understanding and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: try `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y`

Answer (score 9):

Although your kernel build string contains "16.04.1", you are probably running all up to date.

Your kernel build string does not indicate the state of the packages your system has installed. The tool to use is `lsb_release`. E.g.:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Your kernel installed appears to be the hardware enablement variant: [linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04). The one you are running is the latest one available.